# Magento 2 Auto added product's image missing in the checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs, magento2.2.4, ajaxaddtocart

I have created a small module to add a product automatically at cart when a specific coupon code is applied. All is working fine except the product image is missing for the first time, but it shows the image after a refreshing full page.

[image: product image missing in the checkout page]

In my findings, KnockoutJS is working on this section to generate image/dom related stuff. Dom is not being ready properly as the product is added automatically.

I am not really sure what to do. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

**Update:** I added a new repo on GitHub for code review as it contains more codes. Please follow the [link](https://github.com/milanu13/magento2-buy-x-get-y-free).

Comment: add your script that you tried, it will easy to help.

Comment: @SohelRana updated code link in the above. thank you.

Comment: I am having this problem as well. Does anyone know the answer?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/157432)

Answer (score 2):

When a customer visits `/checkout` the product image is stored in: `window.checkoutConfig.imageData`.

Since you are adding the product with a coupon code, the page is never refreshed, so the imageData is never updated with the new product.

If you want to avoid the page refresh, then you could create a mix-in to show a default thumbnail.

1. create `reuirejs-config.js` file at Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js:

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details/thumbnail': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/view/summary/item/details/thumbnail-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

2. Create JS Mixin File: `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/item/details/thumbnail-mixin.js`

```
/**
 * Mixin to add a default thumbnail image to: magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/item/details/thumbnail.js
 */

define([], function () {
    'use strict';

    const mixin = {

        getSrc: function (item) {
            return this._super() || 'https://placehold.jp/150x150.png';
        },
        getWidth: function (item) {
            return this._super() || 150;
        },
        getHeight: function (item) {
            return this._super() || 150;
        }
    };

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend(mixin);
    };
});
```

FYI - I created an [extension](https://github.com/mikedubinsky/magento2-module-checkout-thumbnail/) to simplify this that you can install with Composer: `composer require mikedubinsky/magento2-module-checkout-thumbnail`

Hope it helps someone! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just a loose thought : could it be a cache related problem ?

As i can see on default luma theme the url of the image looks like :

(.../pub/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/75x75/beff4985b56e3afdbeabfc89641a4582/m/s/msh03-blue_main.jpg)

so could it be that this image is not cached yet ?

At the other hand you can always refresh the block by ajax.